# Demailly Campana Peternell Conjecture for isolated singularities.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

If $M$ is smooth, and $T^*M\to$ Spec$H^0(T^*M,\mathcal{O}(T^*M))$ is a projective birational map, then the conjecture predicts that $M=G/P$ for some semisimple group G and a parabolic $P$. If in addition that Spec$H^0(T^*M,\mathcal{O}(T^*M))$ has as isolated singularity then according to [here Conj 1.3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608143.pdf) one can prove that $M$ must be a projective space – this is S. Mori’s famous theorem on smooth varieties with ample tangent bundle. However I don't really see how this is related to Mori's theorem. Can someone explain why this is true for someone like me who is very ignorant in birational geometry.